# Rotate ROI in a picture

Tags: c++, image, opencv, c++11, image-processing

Given the use-case, I want to rotate a ROI in a specific image. For example I have predefined bounding boxes within a image, and now the task is to rotate the part of the image inside these boxes on behalf of an angle.

Furthermore, the rotation must be inside the bounding boxes, so the ROI is after the transformation cropped.

I tried it with a approach of create a subimage of the bounding box, than rotate it and put it back to the original position in the source image. The problem is, that I have a huge dataset of image ( > 100.000) and I think my method probably slow down the process.

Is there a other way to accomplish this transformation?

Edit: For better understanding
[image: Original Image]

**It is a quick mockup, how it should look after the transformation.**

[image: Rotatet]

Comment: You could be a bit more precise in the description of desired result. A figure or two?

Comment: you did not even provide any details on how you do it so far. how long does it take? what is slow? what would be fast in your opinion? which angles?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I have added two images.

Comment: @Piglet I didn't tested the speed, because I evaluating the possibilities to solve the problem. Maybe it is faster if I don't need to extract the ROI at first.

Comment: to rotate an image you have to create a copy of that image as you cannot read from and write to the same image. you would overwrite unprocessed pixels. if you extract a ROI (deep copy) and rotate that subimage you will create a copy of that subimage just for rotation. as your subimage alread is a copy of the original image you could save one deep copy and write the rotation result directly into the full image. all in all both ways should be pretty fast. is this a one time job?

Comment: just 90 degree rotations? you can use cv::flip and/or transpose operations on the roi

Comment: @Piglet if you rotate a square (equilateral) region 90 degree, can't you do it "in-place" by cyclically swapping each 4 corresponding pixels? Don't think it would be faster, though. And won't work at all for the example above, because of scaling and cropping.

Comment: @Headcrab if you swap pixels you usually have to buffer pixel 2, write pixel 1 to pixel 2 then write buffer to pixel 1. its a copy anyway. I don't think that really matters. this sounds like a one time job to me so performance shouldn't be too critical. at least I can't think of a reason why someone should rotate  regions 90 degrees in 100000 images frequently :)

Comment: @Piglet you can avoid using temporary variable for swapping two values if you really want to, not sure about four values. And in case of such rotation you have to shift 4 values, so using just 1 temporary variable it's only 1/4 of a copy :) It would probably slow down the rotation rather than speeding it up, though. If performance is really a concern, it may help to take the corresponding memory block directly and implement your own rotation, scaling, cropping and whatnot - some parts of OpenCV aren't, actually, that fast and can be easily outperformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mat rotateMatImage (Mat& src, double angle ,Mat& cdst) {

//  Rotate the angle which using warpAffine Methods
Mat rot_mat;
Mat rotated;
cv::Point2f src_center(cdst.cols/2.0F, cdst.rows/2.0F);
rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(src_center, angle, 1.0);

warpAffine(src, rotated, rot_mat, cdst.size(), cv::INTER_CUBIC);

return rotated;
```

}

Refer the documentation http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cv::Mat, yourMat(yourRect) will give you the ROI of the image that should be rotated. The fastest way to do this is to calculate the affine transform needed to rotate the four corners of the ROI to their destination points, and then apply the transform to the ROI. Using ROI selection and affine transform are much faster than doing the pixel operations yourself, but I am not sure if there is a faster method than using affine transform.